# SurveyMonkey API - Developer Inactive

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to use the SurveyMonkey Api. Currently I need to get the Access Token, but when I call the `https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize` url with the right parameters, I get the following response:

```
<h1>Developer Inactive</h1>
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are number of reasons this might happen and you've haven't provided enough information for me to give you a definitive answer. My guess is that you're either passing the incorrect API key in your query string or no API key at all. You can email api-support@surveymonkey.com with details to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check your API key is '**active**' for the application.
Initially you might find the key set to "**waiting**"
SurveyMonkey has a habit of keeping developers waiting for the keys to be accepted.
(Super annoying unfortunately)

Check https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/mykeys

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Token if you are using surveyMonkey Version 3.

webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + api_token);